# PyQt 6: Are there any classes with signals that emit when the device connects/disconnects to/from the internet?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt6

I'm adding a download function to an application that I'm creating. When the user's device's internet connection is lost during a download, I want the download to continue on once the connection is re-established; provided that the application is still running, of course. How can I do this? It appears that there used to be a `QtNetwork.QNetworkSession().stateChanged` signal that could be used to do this but it's deprecated in Qt6 and I can't seem to find an alternative to it.

Comment: Maybe the [`reachability`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qnetworkinformation.html#reachability-prop) property of QNetworkInformation?

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply @musicamante, couldn't login due to problems with 2FA. I've tried that but 1) it does not notice a change in state when I disconnect just my VPN, 2) the instant I disconnect the internet entirely (i.e. click "disconnect" from my network manager), on my Debian system at least, I get `dbus[193905]: arguments to dbus_message_new_method_call() were incorrect, assertion "_dbus_check_is_valid_path (path)" failed in file ../../../dbus/dbus-message.c line 1366.\nThis is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.`

Comment: Right now I'm thinking of starting a `QTimer` to try to `get` some page online every few seconds, and continue the download when successful.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not use Qt6 extensively yet, so I cannot really answer you. Have you checked linux related forums, the Qt forums and their bug report system?

Comment: I will check there as well, thank you.